# Include <%= post.title %> In Confirm Delete Message with Rails Blog

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

*Rails 4.0.1*

*Ruby: 1.9.3p392*

*Windows 7*

**Background**: I'm currently learning Ruby on Rails. I've followed the rubyonrails.org [tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) on setting up a blog with rails, and it worked wonderfully. However, I'm now tinkering with different parts of the code to see how it works in more detail. In my index.html.erb file, I've got a line of code that generates a JS alert when a "delete" link is clicked:

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', post_path(post), 
                       method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Delete Post?' } %>
```

I'm trying to include the post title inside the alert message, so if a post titled "*Lorem Ipsum*" is deleted, the alert will read 'Delete post titled *Lorem Ipsum*?'. I've gone through the guides and done a few searches on SO, but haven't been able to find anything yet.

**Question**: Is there a way to use `<%= post.title %>` inside the confirm message? So far, all my attempts have generated syntax errors.

What I've tried:

```
{ confirm: 'Delete post titled' <%= post.title %> '?' }

{ confirm: 'Delete post titled' %= post.title % '?' }

{ confirm: 'Delete post titled'  @post.title '?' }
```

I realize these are probably pretty stupid attempts, but I'm having trouble finding the syntax to include the post.title in this context.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using string interpolation in ruby

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', post_path(post), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Delete post titled #{post.title}?" } %>
```

Comment: thanks! Initially, I tried { confirm: 'Delete post titled #{post.title}?' } (with single quotes) but once I changed to double quotes, it worked. So Rails only interprets "double quotes" as a string?

Comment: Yep, you got it, you need to use double quotes to use string interpolation specifically. Check out https://rubymonk.com/learning/books/1/chapters/5-strings/lessons/31-string-basics?section=143 if you want more information, hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 1):

`{ confirm: "Delete post titled #{post.title}?" }`

Comment: thanks @pcarvalho, I'd accept yours but I think user answered first